# Heathrow to Gatwick and traffic jam

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, lhr, short-connections, lgw

I will land on Heathrow airport on a Sunday morning (October 23rd, 8:30 am) and take the national express bus directly to Gatwick (bus leaves at 10:05 am). I will have five hours between landing and flying again from the next airport (Next flight leaves at 1:10 pm). I also have no check-in luggage and will do online check-in for all flights. I thought all was good until a friend from London told me it took him twice over 3 hours with that bus due to traffic jam as the bus drives in one of the main highways and suggested that going from Heathrow to city center with the train/subway and from there head to Gatwick would guarantee that I will make it in time. So How is the traffic jam on a Sunday morning in the highway connecting both airports?

Comment: The road was empty on Sunday morning and the bus drived as planned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The roads are the M25 and M23 and early on a Sunday are quite likely to be deserted. There are no significant road works on either at present. Your transit time should be about 45 minutes. With heavy traffic it can take just over an hour. The distance is 38 miles, according to Google Maps.

At the moment [The AA](http://www.theaa.com/route-planner/index.jsp) is showing 57 minutes as there is some delay from an earlier accident and a section of the M25 (the London Orbital) is slow due to lane closure. It shows the distance as 44 miles and 49 minutes for the standard journey time. Note that sections of the M25 are limited to 50 mph during busy periods but, as mentioned, that should not include Sunday mornings.

[National Express](http://www.nationalexpress.com/airports/heathrow-to-gatwick-coach.aspx) shows a single ticket is £20 and both *45  mins – fastest journey time* and *Our direct coach transfer takes just 1 hour 15 minutes† - that's 15 minutes faster than the train, and doesn't involve any changes.* Where the associated note is *Travel time indicative of fastest travel between Heathrow terminals 1,2 & 3 and Gatwick South. Travel times may differ depending on time of travel and at peak travel times.*

The route is:

[image: Route]

and some of the apparent time discrepancies are due to pickups and drop offs and a little bit of travel between stops.

A snip from a [timetable](http://www.nationalexpress.com/Assets/uploads/pdf/timetables/RA25.pdf) is:

[image: Timetable]

At present there are (temporary) roadworks on the M25 and four lanes are down to one (eg see this [camera](http://www.motorwaycameras.co.uk/viewcamera/?motorway=m25&motorwayid=17&cameraid=602)) but nevertheless Google Maps is indicating 37 minutes by car. Coach may take about 10 minutes longer than car, between T5 and N.

Comment: PN, you're pretty sure there is NEVER a traffic jam, at 10-11 on a Sunday? (Not a rhetorical question; I'm just wondering.)

Comment: purely FWIW the bus line claims .. http://www.heathrow.com/transport-and-directions/travel-between-airports .. it is 42 miles and takes "75 minutes".  (Hard to see how they can be so definitive about the time, given the huge variety of traffic conditions.)

Comment: Thanks, I will check this AA website before stepping into the bus.

Comment: I guess the alternative is to take a tube to Victoria, and then, the Gatwick Express train.  But I'm pretty sure all of that takes a solid two hours.

Comment: "deserted" ... :D

Comment: @Mehdi a couple of other useful websites are https://tfl.gov.uk and http://www.nationalrail.co.uk which describe the state of the London Underground ("the tube", i.e. the subway) and cross-country trains. Note that none of these rail services are absolutely guaranteed to be working, especially on weekends, which is when maintenance takes place

Comment: @Mehdi also do a Google route - their data is taken from people using Google maps as a satnav and is quite up-to-date (compare the current vs "without traffic" times).  And *especially on a Sunday* (when there are often engineering works) I recommend origimbo's advice to check the train/tube routes.

Comment: @JoeBlow They're presumably definitive because what they really mean is "It's very unusual for it to take substantially more than 75 minutes."

Comment: @pnuts The point is that congestion is often such that the coach _can't_ maintain its maximum speed. Or even any speed at all.

Comment: E pur si muove.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - that's a very sensible thought; I bet you're right.

Comment: @origimbo its a great point that in a way the bus is MORE reliable than the tube - which sometimes has closed stations, etc.

Comment: @JoeBlow: also, many trains to Gatwick from Victoria are run by Southern Rail, which has been having a major dispute with its staff for most of this year. Trains are currently often delayed, cancelled, and pretty crowded. The bus is probably the better bet for those dates.

Comment: "four lanes are down to one" whoa!

Comment: M25 around Heathrow can be surprisingly busy on a Sunday morning (in my experience) but Southern Trains (to Gatwick) are worse. OP your schedule is fairly realistic.