# Traffic from Heathrow to Gatwick

Tags: airport-transfer, lhr, traffic, lgw

I am flying in to London Heathrow on Feb 18th 2017. My flight is landing at 8.20 and I will take a pre-booked taxi/cab to Gatwick airport. My flight out from Gatwick departs at 11.35.

My question is what is the road traffic likely to be on this Saturday morning?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80465/heathrow-to-gatwick-and-traffic-jam

Comment: Perhap the question needs some more details. If the departing flight is international, you're advised to arrive 3 hours before departure in which case the poster is risking being denied check in. Learned the hard way in 2014 being a typical last minuter myself. http://www.heathrow.com/departures/checking-in

Comment: Traffic on the M4 -> M25 -> M23 Heathrow to Gatwick will be comparatively  LIGHT, but your time frame does not account for landing activities. So you are playing this one very (indeed VERY) close to the knuckle.

Comment: That's a fairly doable connection if you only have carry on, but it is dicey if you need to collect and re-check bags. Consider doing carrying on only.

Answer (score 4):

I considered editing Joren's answer but it gets complicated so let me expand on it in a separate answer.

You can use Google Maps to estimate, here's what you need to enter:

2. For Terminal 2: [Heathrow Terminal 2, Nelson Road, Hounslow, UK](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Heathrow+Terminal+2/@51.469801,-0.4541379,17z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sHeathrow+Terminal+2,+Heathrow+Airport+(LHR),+Nelson+Rd,+Longford,+Hounslow+TW6+2GW,+UK!3m4!1s0x487672284479c2bb:0x28c4239a0992f238!8m2!3d51.469573!4d-0.4495923)
3. For Terminal 3: [Heathrow Short Stay Car Park Terminal 3, Heathrow Airport (LHR), 521 Stansted Rd, Longford, Hounslow TW6 1QG, UK](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Heathrow+Short+Stay+Car+Park+Terminal+3/@51.3312238,-0.5947309,10z/data=!4m21!1m15!4m14!1m6!1m2!1s0x487673cce6be1893:0xeb22c8ae2be0287c!2sHeathrow+Short+Stay+Car+Park+Terminal+3,+Heathrow+Airport+(LHR),+521+Stansted+Rd,+Longford,+Hounslow+TW6+1QG,+UK!2m2!1d-0.455507!2d51.470512!1m6!1m2!1s0x4875f02730ca946d:0xaa77a1cd73a8045e!2sGatwick+Airport+Station,+Gatwick+Airport,+Horley,+Crawley+RH6+0RD,+UK!2m2!1d-0.1611417!2d51.1566381!3m4!1s0x0:0xeb22c8ae2be0287c!8m2!3d51.4705119!4d-0.4555068).
4. For Terminal 4: [Heathrow Airport, Southern Perimeter Rd, London TW6 3XA, UK](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Heathrow+Airport+Terminal+4/@51.4590788,-0.4477809,18z/data=!4m15!1m9!4m8!1m0!1m6!1m2!1s0x48767234c7ef84e1:0x848b8da26f0ebaf7!2sHeathrow+Airport+Terminal+4,+Heathrow+Airport,+Southern+Perimeter+Rd,+London+TW6+3XA,+UK!2m2!1d-0.4468369!2d51.4593682!3m4!1s0x0:0x848b8da26f0ebaf7!8m2!3d51.459368!4d-0.4468369)
5. For Terminal 5: [Heathrow T5, Wellington Rd, Longford, Hounslow TW6, UK](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Heathrow+T5/@51.4723627,-0.4916895,17z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sHeathrow+T5,+Wellington+Rd,+Longford,+Hounslow+TW6,+UK!3m4!1s0x4876719e19e8b1df:0x722110f87a04450c!8m2!3d51.4725628!4d-0.489706)

And you are going to Gatwick Airport [Gatwick Airport Station, Gatwick Airport, Horley, Crawley RH6 0RD, UK](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Gatwick+Airport+Station/@51.1566414,-0.1633357,17z/data=!4m15!1m9!4m8!1m0!1m6!1m2!1s0x4875f02730ca946d:0xaa77a1cd73a8045e!2sGatwick+Airport+Station,+Gatwick+Airport,+Horley,+Crawley+RH6+0RD,+UK!2m2!1d-0.1611417!2d51.1566381!3m4!1s0x4875f02730ca946d:0xaa77a1cd73a8045e!8m2!3d51.1566381!4d-0.1611417)

While T2 and T3 are very close neither T4 nor T5 is.

Comment: Google maps does understand "Heathrow airport terminal 4", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that your car would depart at 9:00, your ride would take 35-45 minutes. You would arrive at 9:45.

[Google map's prediction](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/Heathrow+Airport+(LHR),+Longford,+Hounslow+TW6,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/Luchthaven+Londen+Gatwick,+Horley,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.3138972,-0.8871917,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m17!4m16!1m5!1m1!1s0x48767234cdc56de9:0x8fe7535543f64167!2m2!1d-0.4542955!2d51.4700223!1m5!1m1!1s0x4875efde7d1f391b:0x59dda4bf018973ff!2m2!1d-0.1820629!2d51.1536621!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1487408520)

Comment: @pnuts Google Maps estimates 35-45 minutes for this route, departing on a Saturday 9AM.

Comment: @pnuts I read your comment as if you disputed Joren's estimate and suggested to use Google Maps instead and didn't realize that you suggested to use different start and end points. BTW, Google Maps does not understand 'Verenigd Koninkrijk', unless it is set to Dutch language.